# Arduino ESP8266: can't find pyhon executable file?

Tags: linux, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I've been working with Arduino for some years now and just hit the wall with this strange error:

```
exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH Error compiling for board Generic ESP8266 Module.
```

My environment:
- PC with Ubuntu 18.04
- Arduino IDE 1.8.5
- Python 2.7.15 rc1 installed, it runs if you type "python" in a terminal

It's the first time since I'm working with Arduino that I get a python related error.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide the output of `echo $PATH`. It seems python misconfiguration after multiple installations. Typing python in terminal and working doesn't mean that Arduino can find it.

Comment: also `which python` output.

Answer (score -1):

Install pyserial in Python 2.x.  Serial will not work.

I realize that this is getting a little long in the tooth, just added solution for future reference.